# how do I get the nautilus navigation buttons and side panel back?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

Since the upgrade, the navigation buttons and the side panel in nautilus file browser windows ahve gone missing. I'm not sure what got messed up, but none of the toggles for nautilus in gconf seem to restore this.

How do I get Nautilus to reset to the Ubuntu 11.10 defaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think nautilus has switched to the new dconf backend.

Using 'dconf-editor' does the trick for me. Settings for nautilus is in 'org.gnome.nautilus'.

Comment: That was the ticket. Love it when they change this stuff and require a tool that isn't installed by default to fix the issues with it.